# Get the row data using javascript in devextreme grid

Tags: javascript, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I am using devextreme dxdatagrid tables. in that case if I am clicking to a row in  **OnEditorPreparing** event to retrieve the data on that row.

```
     function editorPreparing(e) {
         console.log(e.row);
        }
```

when I clicked the row and use e.row, I can easily get what is the value in the row.
[image]

However when using

```
       console.log(e.row.data);
```

I get an error such [image]

Is there any way to retrieve the row values.

Comment: do you have a live example for that! I cannot imagine that doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you use [onEditorPreparing](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onEditorPreparing) event to get the row data, I would use [onRowClick](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onRowClick) instead, you can see it in the example below:

```
onRowClick: function (e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        }
```